# error in linear layout.vertical. what should be the exact line

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, linearlayoutmanager

```
mUserListLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayout.VERTICAL, false);
```

LinearLayout.Vertical is creating a warning

Comment: What does the warning say??

Answer (score 3):

Since you didn't post the warning message, I'm going to jump to conclusions and assume:

You should use `LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL` instead of `LinearLayout.VERTICAL`.